# I need help correcting my code for blueJ

Tags: bluej

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    /**
     * Write a description of class code here.
     *
     * @author (your name)
     * @version (a version number or a date)
     */
    public class code
    {
        public static void main(String args [])
        {
            {
                docreditcard(); // calls functions
            }
            {
                public static void docreditcard()
            }
            {
                float preb = 0;
                float add = 0;
                float inter = 0;
                float newb = 0;
                float minp = 0;

                preb = getPreviousB();
                add = getAdditional();
                inter = getInterest(preb,add);
                newb = getNewb(preb,add,inter);
                minp = getMinpay(newb);

            }
            public static float getPreviousB()
            {
                Scanner cd = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter previous balance");
                return cd.nextFloat();
            }
            public static float getAdditional()
            {
                Scanner cd = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter total new charges");
                return cd.nextFloat();
            }
            public static float getInterest(float preb,float add)
            {
            float interest = 0;
            if(preb == 0)
            {
                interest = 0;
                return interest;
            }
            else
            {
                interest = ( preb + add)*0.020;
                return interest;
            }
        }

        public static float getNewb(float preb,float add,float inter)
        {
            float newbalance = 0;
            newbalance = (preb + add + interest);
            return newbalance;
        }

        public static float getMinpay(float newb)
        {
            float minimal = 0;
            if(newbalance < 50)
            {
                minimal = newbalance;
                return minimal;
            }
            else if( newbalace >= 50 && newbalance <= 300)
            {
                minimal = 50;
                return minimal;
            }
            else
            {
                minimal = (newbalance)*.020;
                return minimal;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("CS International Card  Statement");
        System.out.println("====================\n");
        System.out.println("Previous Balance:\t $%.2f%n",preb);  // prints 
        System.out.println("Additional Charges:\t $%.2f%n",add);  
        System.out.println("Interest:\t\t$%.2f%n",inter);  
        System.out.println("\nNew Balance:\t\t$%.2f%n",newb);  
        System.out.println("Minimum Payment:\t$%.2f%n",minp);  
    }
    }
```

//  The program should take user input for previous balance and total new charges. Then should calculate interest,new balance(previous balance + additional charges + interest) and minimal pay. If previous balance is 0, interest is 0 else interest is 20% of previous balance and additional charges. For minimal pay, if new balance less than 50, it equals to minimal pay,else if between 50 and 300, minimal pay is 50 and if higher, then minimal pay is 20% of new balance

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve the errors for your program but i was able to make my own version for it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

class code
{

```
public static void main(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter previous balance and total new charges");
    double pbal = sc.nextDouble();
    double tnc = sc.nextDouble();
    double nbal,interest,mp=0.0;

    if(pbal == 0){
        interest = 0.0;
        nbal=pbal+ tnc;
    }
    else{ 
        interest = (pbal+tnc)*0.2;//0.2=20/100
        nbal=pbal + interest + tnc;
    }
    if(nbal<50){
        mp=nbal;
    }
    if(nbal>50 && nbal<300){
        mp=50;
    }
    if(nbal>300){
     mp=nbal *0.2;   //0.2=20/100
    }
    System.out.println("old balance" + pbal + " " + "total new charges" + tnc);
    System.out.println("new balance" + nbal + " " + "interest" + interest + " " + "minimal pay" + mp);

}
```

}

Hope this helps.